# Process (only) resources from library (no in dependencies) in multiproject

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a multiproject deployment in Android Studio where the projects are libraries (except by the main project app).

Structure is something as:

```
+ app
    + manifest
    + java
    + res
+ library 1
    + manifest
    + java
    + res
        + layout
        + values
        + xml
    + assets
+ library 2
    + ....
```

I need to configure build.gradle to include specific resources from the libraries (as xml, strings or fonts) in the compile of the main app (in my case I have different flavors).

I could include the whole project for every flavor but it would be unnecessary to include all the java files an other resources as they are no used by this specific flavour. However, the main app will need still to use fonts and some strings.xml, fonts or xml icons from libraries.

What would be the instruction to be added in the flavor description in the build.gradle to include (only) these specific resources from libraries (instead the whole libraries)?

UPDATE

---

I am trying to include these resources in the sourceSets by adding to the build.gradle the following:

```
sourceSets {
    main.resources.srcDirs += '/home/username/AndroidStudioProjects/Lib1/lib1/src/main/res/values'
    main.resources.srcDirs += new File("/home/username/AndroidStudioProjects/Lib1/lib1/src/main/res/values").absolutePath
    main.resources.srcDirs += new File('/home/username/AndroidStudioProjects/Lib1/lib1/src/main/res/values').absolutePath
    main.resources.srcDirs += new File(new URI("file:///home/username/AndroidStudioProjects/Lib1/lib1/src/main/res/values")).absolutePath
    main.resources.srcDirs += '../../Lib1/lib1/src/main/resources/values'
    main.resources.srcDirs += '../../Lib1/lib1/src/main/res/values'
    main.resources.srcDirs += '../../Lib1/lib1/src/main/resources/xml'
    main.resources.srcDirs += '../../Lib1/lib1/src/main/assets'
    main.resources.srcDirs += 'project(Lib1).sourceSets.main.srcDirs'
    main.resources.srcDirs += 'project(:Lib1).sourceSets.main.srcDirs'
    main.resources.srcDirs += 'project(:..:Lib1).sourceSets.main.srcDirs'
}
```

Some of these combinations is expected to work but I do not see any update on the lib resources in the intermediates or generated folders.

UPDATE: as there is not a clear answer for this issue, I opened a bug request in gradle's forum. Follow here: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/sourcesets-for-paths-not-belonging-to-projects-added-as-dependencies/12720/2

Comment: You cannot just exclude the unused resources from the final apk?

Comment: what i do not like of this approach is that it would still compile all the libraries for all the flavors and this is overkill (I have a lot of libraries). There must be some cleaner way to cherry picking specific resources from libraries when compiling main app flavors

Comment: hum, you dont want to call some libraries that are not totally used, right?

Comment: yes, only some resources as fonticons and specific strings are used, an small part of these libraries that do not need a whole compilation

Comment: As far I understand, you cannot import or use other project resources unless you import the project. Only you can copy the resource from that project and paste in your project, when needed.

Comment: This is what I am afraid, so I created another thread to understand the internals http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33663499/how-a-sourcesets-definition-internally-works-in-gradle However, (1) if this is something against gradle policies it should be welknown, (2) if it is a bug, it should be reported or (3) maybe we are doing something wrong

Comment: By the way, I asked in the gradle forum, but not response so far. Kind of mistery https://discuss.gradle.org/t/adding-external-resources-to-sourcesets-in-android/12704

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to attach the library to the flavour. But with this method you cannot use the library at all for that flavour.

```
myflavourCompile 'com.lib:libraryname:0.0.3'
```

Comment: problem with this is that I can have 10 libraries per flavour and it would overkill the compilation as I have several flavours as well.... when I just want some resources (e.g. fonticons and strings)

Comment: Even after attaching library giving error resource drawable/ic_emoji_food_holo_dark not found