# How a sourceSets definition internally works in gradle?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I want to make a proof of concept. I want to try if gradle supports sourceSets from other projects (no referenced in dependencies) or even external paths.

To do this I want to understand how it normally works with resourcesd defined in dependencies. So, for example, lets suppose we do a definition of:

```
sourceSets {
    main.resources.srcDirs += '/src/flavour1/res'
}
```

What this definition means? How this resources are copied to either intermediates, generated, output or tmp folder? Anyone knows?

I have tried to find out experimentally but I cannot explain what this definition of sourceSets internally implies...

By knowing this I would be able to test if resources from another project can also be imported, e.g.

```
sourceSets {
    main.resources.srcDirs += '../../Lib/lib/src/main/assets'
}
```

UPDATE: as there is not a clear answer for this issue, I opened a bug request in gradle's forum. Follow here: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/sourcesets-for-paths-not-belonging-to-projects-added-as-dependencies/12720/2

Comment: Wouldn't you be able to already do `sourceSets { main.resources.srcDirs = project(Lib).sourceSets.main.srcDirs }`

Comment: from the java source code trying to use this Lib resources, which I would expect being available after running the build.gradle, no, I tried and they are not available. I tried Lib and :Lib. Internally, I do not know. Clarify that Lib is not included as a dependency. If Lib would be included as dependency, then I think it would be available (which is the common case)

Comment: You should stick with gradle source folder conventions as much as possible. If Lib is a dependency, why not add it as such?

Comment: Well, you are right. Is a dependency only for some flavours. It does not work for those flavours that is not a dependency.

Comment: I opened an issue in gradle's bugs list since I think is an important thing. How can you have a deployment tool which is unclear what paths can be added to the project or not? https://discuss.gradle.org/t/sourcesets-for-paths-not-belonging-to-projects-added-as-dependencies/12720